# Python escape "class" word inside string

Tags: python, escaping, cpu-word

i just writing a class for html utility but i have this error on "class" word

```
html=f"<table{(f" class='{tableclass}'") if tableclass else ""} {(f" {tableextra}") if tableextra else ""}>"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

vscode get me this

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 4)pylint(syntax-error)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either you forgot to close the first f-string or you have a nested f-string unnecessarily (and I'm not sure if it is possible at all).

Comment: Can you show what the values of the input variables are and what the formatted string is supposed to look like?

Comment: @mkrieger1 are None by default, i just check if i missed some close, but are all closed

Comment: i tried to use normal string istead f-string and continue to give me error

Comment: When you nest f-strings, they can't both use the same type of quote delimiter. So if the outer one is `f"..."` the inner one has to be `f'...'`

Comment: Apparently the parser is simply looking for the matching quote before parsing the `{}` replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

When `tableclass` and `tableextra` are both `None`

```py
tableclass = None
tableextra = None

html = '<table{}{}>'.format(f' class="{tableclass}"' if tableclass else '', f' {tableextra}' if tableextra else '')
print(html) # '<table>'
```

When they are not `None`

```py
tableclass='test-class'
tableextra='a="b"'

html = '<table{}{}>'.format(f' class="{tableclass}"' if tableclass else '', f' {tableextra}' if tableextra else '')
print(html) # <table class="test-class" a="b">
```